# Aginity workbench for Netezza does not give syntax error for large queries

Tags: syntax-error, netezza

I have noticed several times that running Netezza queries which are long (in terms of code length not performance) and syntactically wrong does not provide a well defined error message in Aginity and just gives a catchall error (ERROR 42000). Is there a way to get the exact error which causes the code to fail (as in Oracle) for large queries?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may find that the error message is truncated from the end of the string returned using the ODBC driver with Aginity.  Try using the OLE-DB driver when connecting with Aginity instead, as I have found it to retain the full error text from larger queries.